# Need to perform mathematical operation on SQL query with multiple joins on same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm using WordPress for custom fields, and it basically has a `meta_key` column and a `meta_value` column in `wp_postmeta` table which I am using to store `meta_keys` 'longitude' and 'latitude' with `meta_values` say, 24.3 and 76.2 for one `post_id` of type 'gym'.

Now I need to query the database from Php to find the nearby gyms from the user position within a 10km radius. I am using the following query:

```
                 SELECT
                 pm1.meta_value AS longitude,
                 pm2.meta_value AS latitude,
                 ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( pm2.meta_value ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $user_lat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( pm2.meta_value ) )
                * COS( RADIANS( $user_lat )) * COS( RADIANS( pm1.meta_value ) - RADIANS( $user_lng )) ) * $earth_radius AS distance 

                 FROM `wp_postmeta` pm1
                   INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` pm2 ON pm1.post_id = pm2.post_id

                 WHERE
                   pm1.meta_key = 'longitude'
                   AND pm2.meta_key = 'latitude'
                   AND ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( pm2.meta_value ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $user_lat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( pm2.meta_value ) )
                * COS( RADIANS( $user_lat )) * COS( RADIANS( pm1.meta_value ) - RADIANS( $user_lng )) ) * $earth_radius < 10
```

where `$user_lat` and `$user_lng` are Php variables denoting user position. This isn't working. The syntax seems to be correct but the calculated distances not. I got the inspiration for the query from [radius search with google maps and mysql](http://spinczyk.net/blog/2009/10/04/radius-search-with-google-maps-and-mysql/)

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** The above code works. I was making a very silly mistake. Above code is a great resource for people facing the same problem where `longitude` and `latitude` fields aren't clearly defined, for example in the default WordPress custom fields table layout.

Comment: I don't think 6371 is for km.  Are you getting too many or two few rows?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just calculate distance between each gym  and user position, and return the ones where distance <=10km?

For example:

User coordinates = (7, 2)

Gym1 coordinates = (2,4)
Gym2 coordinates = (10,3)
...

distance1 = sqrt((7-2)^2+(2-4)^2)
distance2 = sqrt((7-10)^2+(2-3)^2)
...

Comment: btw that formula doesn't work for longitude and latityudes... it's more complicated than that...

Comment: Yeah, I just realised the distance formula is differnt due to curvature of the earth. Maybe the formula you found isn't correct.

Comment: yeah maybe because the distance isn't correct no matter what I do. even in my new queries

Comment: what's the value of $earth_radius?

Comment: `$earth_radius` is 6371, in kms. But its an int value.

Comment: How do you know the calculated distance is wrong? Can you give an example?

Comment: so I know the position im getting of the user (me) is correct. A gym that I placed in the database which is 2 minutes walking distance from myself, shows a distance of 3000 km, 8000km etc, which is absurd. Thats how i know its wrong.

Comment: I just tested it using my coordinates and I'm getting correct distance. Check your coordinates.

Comment: okay so you're right. the problem was that i was using another code from before and it was manipulating my `$user_lat` and `$user_lng` before it went into value. very VERY silly mistake. Lesson learned: check the basic workflow if you're really banging your head on the problem. thank you :) your comment helped